# Append a value on automatically populated field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

function below lets me auto populate Field2 with whatever values entered from Field1. Field1 is a select list.

```
$("#Field1").change(function(){
    $("#Field2").val(this.value);
});
```

I managed to come up with the ff. which appends the string abc.

```
$("#Field1").change(function(){
    $("#Field2").val(this.value += "abc");
});

Output:
Field 1: Option1
Field 2: Option2abc
```

The Problem. The value on Field1 is not being saved when the form is submitted, ignoring the values entered on Field1.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save values on the Field1 on client between submitting form you can accomplish that by saving values in cookies, and restore it after form load:

cookie saving functinons: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

usage:

```
  //save
    $("#Field1").change(function(){
        $("#Field2").val(this.value += "abc");
        setCookie("Field2",this.value += "abc",10);
    });

   //restore
    $(function(){
       var Field2=getCookie("Field2");
       if (Field2!=null && Field2!=""){
       $("#Field2").val(Field2);
    }
    });
```

Otherwise you should track values of sumited forms on server side, and write new values after form submit to fields.